# How to display in a new window the last item of each dictionary in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Trying to program an experiment using TrialHandler, I succeeded in making and printing a list of dictionaries of the following form:

```
[
    {
        'sentence': 'I am currently working',
        'variable1': 1,
        'variable2': 10
    },
    {
        'sentence': 'How are you today?',
        'variable1': 2,
        'variable2': 20
    }, # ... etc.
]
```

Each dictionary describes the characteristics of the trial. The whole list of dictionaries contains all the trials of the experiment. Is it possible to select the sentence part of each dictionary and show the sentences one by one in a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> d = [
...     {
...         'sentence': 'I am currently working',
...         'variable1': 1,
...         'variable2': 10
...     },
...     {
...         'sentence': 'How are you today?',
...         'variable1': 2,
...         'variable2': 20
...     },
... ]
>>>
>>> "\n".join(x['sentence'] for x in d)
'I am currently working\nHow are you today?'
>>> print "\n".join(x['sentence'] for x in d)
I am currently working
How are you today?
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of sentences using a list comprehension:

```
listOfDict = [{'variable1':1, 'variable2':10, 'sentence':'I am currently working'},
              {'variable1':2, 'variable2':20, 'sentence':'How are you today?'}]

sentences = [d['sentence'] for d in listOfDict]
print(sentences)
```

which prints out:

```
['I am currently working', 'How are you today?']
```